# Angular 2 Fire Multiples Observable with Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I have this function to get information of user rooms in Firebase, at first time I request the reference of chats ID with `users-chats/user`, with this result i do a combineLatest to get the members of specific room.. and before that  I want to request the member information(from MongoDB) and this is my problem. I can return the reference of members ID and show in the template with Async Pipe.. But when I try to get the member information, the ngFor doesnt show nothing

I need the Users-chats and Members of any Rooms in real time, but the Member Information I only whant to request this one time

```
public getRoomsByUser(userID: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.af.database.object(`users-chats/${userID}`).mergeMap(rooms => {
        rooms = Object.keys(rooms).map(key => rooms[key]);
        if (rooms)
            return Observable.combineLatest(
                rooms.map(room => this.af.database.object(`members/${room}`)),
                (...members) => {
                    return rooms.map((room, index) => {
                        //I want to make http request here with the members, to get the data of every member
                        return { id: room, members: members[index] }
                    })
                })
        else
            return Observable.empty()

    })

}
```

[image: Inside the members have the Reference ID of the chat.. and inside that is the reference id in mongo of user]

Inside the members have the Reference ID of the chat.. and inside that is the reference id in mongo of user

Comment: How is `this.as.showUser(member)` implemented?

Comment: showUser(id: string) {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/users/${id}`, '');
    }

Comment: I can see several problems: the `values` in `(...values)` does not appear to be used; and neither of the `rooms.map((room, index) =>` arrow function bodies return anything.

Comment: Please check the code again, is the original that works, but i need to make the request  inside the function of ```return rooms.map...```

Comment: I think you should put some more work into the question. What works? What doesn't? What's it supposed to do? Why use `object` for the rooms? Why not `list`? And - most important - include some representative data.

Comment: The code works... I get all the rooms of a user with the USERID,after that I get the members ID of every member of the room.. Here is where my problem comes .. after this I want to get the information of each member, already having his ID